# Is there any way in angular js to sequence the order of execution of functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ajax

am facing problem in execution function in desired order.

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
   var promiseObj= $http.get('Some Url');

  /* other logic goes here */
}

$scope.function2 = function(){
   var promiseObj= $http.get('Some Url');

  /* other logic goes here */
}

$scope.function3 = function(){
   var promiseObj= $http.get('Some Url');

  /* other logic goes here */
}
```

Now, want to execute function in following order,

1) `function1`

2) `function2`

3) `function3`

And I want `function2` and `function3` to be executed only after `function1` completes
its execution.

I have tried the following approach,

```
$.when(
  $scope.function1()
).then(
   $scope.function2(),
   $scope.function3()
      )
```

Still, it didn't work . First function2 gets executed then function1

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> $.when(
>    $scope.function1()
> ).then(
>   $scope.function2(),
>   $scope.function3()
> )
> ```

You are passing result of execution to callback, while wanting to pass the whole code inside of `then` as a callback. The correct version will be:

```
$.when(
  $scope.function1()
).then(function () {
  $scope.function2(),
  $scope.function3()
})
```

`$.when` seems strange still. Why do you mix angular with something else? Just use:

```
$scope.function1().then(function () {
  $scope.function2(),
  $scope.function3()
})
```

Ensure that `function1` returns promice.

Answer (score 2):

Your functions aren't returning anything but they need to return the `$http` promises.

Since they aren't returning promises `$.when` resolves immediately

Also no need to use jQuery when angular has `$q` promises built in and `$http` returns a $q promise

Functions need to look more like:

```
var function1 = function(){
   var promiseObj= $http.get('Some Url').then(function(response){
       var data = response.data;
       // do something to data here, and return it
       return data
   });    
   // return the promise
   return promiseObj; 
}
```

now you can do something like:

```
function1()
  .then(function2)
  .then(function3)
```

Or if the second and third can be sent simultaneously after the first:

```
function1().then(function(func1Data){
   // can use func1Data  here if needed since it was returned to prior `then()`
   function2();
   function3();
});
```

Also note no need to make these functions scope properties since they are not going to be passed to the view. Only use scope for view related objects

Answer (score 0):

First thing:  Your functions must return a promise like:

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
   var defer = $q.defer();
   var promiseObj= $http.get('Some Url');

   /* other logic goes here */
   defer.resolve(response);
   return defer.promise;
}
```

Or:

```
$scope.function1 = function(){
   return $http.get('Some Url');
}
```

Then you can chain your functions like this:

```
$scope.function1.then(function(response1) {
    $scope.function2.then(function(response2) {
        $scope.function3.then(function(response3) {
            // do some stuff
        }).catch(function(err){})
    }).catch(function(err){})
}).catch(function(err){})
```

There are also some strategires to flatten this chains, for more information read [this](http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/).

Comment: Why to use jQuery promice in angularjs application? Are you sure that you didn't miss some `$scope.$apply` calls in such case?

Comment: Also, what about promise chaining?

Comment: Using a new `$q.defer()` is a common anti-pattern when `$http` already returns a promise. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it